# In Blade Runner 2049, graffiti on a door reads "____ off Skinner". Any indication that this is a Simpsons reference?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

I wonder if anyone has suggested this, some bleed from our world into the fictional world. Why call a "skin job" "Skinner" if not from Principal Skinner in Simpsons?

Comment: I am pretty sure it was just a reference to the fact that someone (or everyone?) in his apartment building knew he was a police replicant. And derogatory slang for a replicant is a "skin job". so calling him a Skinner is just a more derogatory slang.

Comment: What on earth is this question?

Answer (score 1):

"Skin job" is indeed a derogatory slang term for a replicant, as we see in the opening of The Workprint Version of the original *Blade Runner*.

[image]

"Skinner" appears to be an even more derogatory slur, likely meant to evoke the n-word. It also exists to demonstrate that language trends have changed somewhat in the three decades between the films, just as languages evolve in real life.

Comment: I understand clearly from the context that "skinner" is a variant of "skin job." However, is this variant plausible? You say it evokes perhaps the n-word, not sure I find that compelling. What is interesting to me is the possibility that what the humans are taking issue with is not just that he is a replicant but that he kills ("skins" as hunters skin their prey) other replicants but would humans actually object to this profession? That is why I suggest that "skinner", while it might simply be a variant, might also  be an insult based on indeed the Simpsons character.

Comment: @Jeff I think you're over-thinking it. I don't see any reason to believe it's a reference to the Simpsons character.

Comment: I can't prove it of course, but I think unintentionally perhaps the writers or set dressers were influenced by something since "skinner" does not feel plausible as a variant of skin job otherwise. That's all I can say.

Comment: @Jeff: Maybe they were influenced by ... [Skinner, the surname](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skinner_(surname)) (not specifically from the Simpsons)? Judging by the length of the list of notable people with that name, it doesn't seem to be a particularly seldom surname.